# Plotting Network with LayeredGraphPlot with specific order

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I have a network and want to plot it.
I use `LayeredGraphPlot`, and the network is described as:

```
NetList={"A1" -> "a1", "A1" -> "b1", "b1" -> "A2", "a1" -> "a2", "A2" -> "b2",
"A2" -> "c2", "a2" -> "B3", "b2" -> "B3", "c2" -> "c3", "B3" -> "a3",
"B3" -> "b3", "a3" -> "A4", "b3" -> "A4", "c3" -> "c4", "A4" -> "a4",
"A4" -> "b4"};
LayeredGraphPlot[NetList, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Result:

[image: GraphPlot]

I have two question:

*1) Main question:*
How can I tell `LayeredGraphPlot` to put all `a1, a2, a3, a4` in one vertical line, and `b1, b2, b3, b4` in one line, and `c2, c3, c4` in one vertical line? (the `c`-elements are already in a vertical line coincidencely for this network).

*2) Minor question:*
If I only want to have labeling for certain elements (such as the upper-case Elements `A1, A2, B3, A4`), how can I modify the LayeredGraphPlot-instruction?

**Update**

ad1) One methode to do this is `VertexCoordinateRules` - i'm afraid it doesnt get much easier than that.

**Update2**

With the nice solution of hftf (below), the example above works perfectly. However, there is a problem with different networks.

When I have:

```
NetList={"A1" -> "a1", "A1" -> "b1", "b1" -> "A2", "a1" -> "a2", "A2" -> "b2",
    "A2" -> "c2", "a2" -> "B3", "c2" -> "B3", "b2" -> "b3", "B3" -> "a3",
    "B3" -> "c3", "a3" -> "A4", "c3" -> "A4", "b3" -> "b4", "A4" -> "a4",
    "A4" -> "c4"};
GraphPlot[NetList, VertexLabeling -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> coords, 
    DirectedEdges -> True]
```

I get the following:

[image: GraphPlot2]

The problem is, that `b2` -> `B3` and `b3` -> `A4`, even though there is no rule in `NetList` for that. It happens because `B3` and `A4` are somehow *in the way* of b.
In the documentary of `LayeredGraphPlot`, there are several examples how edges *go around* vertices that are in the way. But I could not get that work for my example. The error it tells me is

> LayeredGraphPlot::vprmtd: Warning: the VertexCoordinateRules option with rule list value is only supported for the SpringElectricalEmbedding method. Switching to the SpringElectricalEmbedding method.

If I try using `SpringElectricalEmbedding`, it complains about the `VertexCoordinateRules`.

Is there a simple way around these hurdles?
On solution would be to define the positions of As and Bs at some fractional position. But maybe there is some nicer way, where the edges go around the vertices in the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your main question, I generated the `coords` as specified:

```
coords = Flatten[
  Array[(Characters@"abc")[[#]] <> ToString@#2 -> {#, #2} &,
    {3, 4}
  ], 1]

{"a1" -> {1, 1}, "a2" -> {1, 2}, "a3" -> {1, 3}, "a4" -> {1, 4}, 
 "b1" -> {2, 1}, "b2" -> {2, 2}, "b3" -> {2, 3}, "b4" -> {2, 4}, 
 "c1" -> {3, 1}, "c2" -> {3, 2}, "c3" -> {3, 3}, "c4" -> {3, 4}}
```

and passed them to `VertexCoordinateRules` in a normal `GraphPlot`:

```
netList = {"A1" -> "a1", "A1" -> "b1", "b1" -> "A2", "a1" -> "a2", 
   "A2" -> "b2", "A2" -> "c2", "a2" -> "B3", "b2" -> "B3", 
   "c2" -> "c3", "B3" -> "a3", "B3" -> "b3", "a3" -> "A4", 
   "b3" -> "A4", "c3" -> "c4", "A4" -> "a4", "A4" -> "b4"};
GraphPlot[netList,
  VertexLabeling -> True,
  VertexCoordinateRules -> coords,
  DirectedEdges -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!! (+1) for the vertex labels piece you can use something like `VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Yellow, EdgeForm[Gray], 
    Rectangle[# - {.2, .2}, {.2, .2} + #], Black, 
    Text[If[LowerCaseQ[StringTake[#2, 1]], "", #2], #1]} &)`

Comment: Wonderful solution, much easier than I expected it to become. Thanks alot! :)

Comment: @kguler: Thanks, I didnt know one can use If in the `VertexReneringFunction`. This also works for the other arguments - especially for the first one, so it's pretty useful. Thank you!

Comment: I used this method for a different network, and observed a _problem_. I've explained it in detail in Update2 above.