# Graph plotting: specify layers for layered drawing

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

Mathematica can do layered graph drawing with `LayeredGraphPlot` or `GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"`.  Is it possible to specify which node goes on which layer instead of letting the system figure this out?  Determining the precise location on the layer would be left to the layout algorithm.

Comment: Would you please include an example of the input and the rendered output that you desire?

Comment: Relevant Mathematica feature is `VertexCoordinateRules`, e.g. setting the x value of nodes to `Automatic` and specify a `y` value. However, this does not work with all layout methods. Another question asking from my point of view the same is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46018/plotting-network-with-layeredgraphplot-with-specific-order.