# "Automatic" in Graph VertexCoorindates?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is it possible to add edges to a graph while preserving the structure?
This is similar to [preserving structure while deleting a node](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105400/6506), but that method is tailored for removing nodes and doesn't obviously help when adding edges.

Consider a triangle (cycle graph), where I want to think of the three vertices as "external" while adding an "internal" vertex between vertices 1 and 2:

```
start = CycleGraph[3, VertexLabels->Automatic];
badEnd = EdgeAdd[EdgeDelete[start, 1 <-> 2], {1 <-> internal, 2 <-> internal}];
(* I don't care where the new node is, just that it's somewhere "between" the 1 and 2 *)
(* Control the location via a and b *)
{a, b} = {0.35, 0.2};
vc =
Join[
 {internal -> (a GraphEmbedding[start][[1]] + b GraphEmbedding[start][[2]])}
 ,
 MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {VertexList[start], GraphEmbedding[start]}]
];
goodEnd = Graph[badEnd,VertexCoordinates -> vc];
```

The `badEnd` Graph displays in a terrible way in this instance.

In contrast, `goodEnd` keeps the three original vertices, and `internal` is generally between vertices 1 and 2, and can be moved around by changing `a` and `b`.

I want a general way of implementing something like `goodEnd`. Ideally would be

```
internal -> Automatic
```

instead of

```
internal -> (a GraphEmbedding[start][[1]] + b GraphEmbedding[start][[2]])
```

in the `vc` list. I'm aware of `Graph[badEnd, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"],` (for example) but the graphs in my real examples do not behave nicely under these layouts.

Comment: related Q/As: [How to add new nodes to an existing graph with fixed (coordinates) nodes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31014/125), and [Graph plotting: specify layers for layered drawing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56245/125)

Comment: I get the sense you're mostly looking for something built-in.  In lieu of that, are you interested in some code to handle this?  It mostly seems like (1) adding a new node to a graph with the previous nodes fixed, plus (2) making sure the new node is placed 'nicely' -- that is (2a) in the interior of the other nodes (which might be slightly nontrivial for `Length@VertexList@start` > 3) and (2b) that the new node is somehow visually nicely placed (e.g., avoiding any nearly-coinciding nearly-parallel edges).  This is not completely trivial, but I'm guessing you've thought about this.