# Layered Graph Drawing: Specify Layer for Nodes

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I was trying to recreate following graphviz graph with Mathematica 11.2:

```
graph {
    rankdir=LR;
    a -- { b c d }; b -- { c e }; c -- { e f }; d -- { f g }; e -- h; f -- { h i j g };
    g -- k; h -- { o l }; i -- { l m j }; j -- { m n k }; k -- { n r }; l -- { o m };
    m -- { o p n }; n -- { q r }; o -- { s p }; p -- { s t q }; q -- { t r }; r -- t;
    s -- z; t -- z;
    { rank=same; b, c, d }
    { rank=same; e, f, g }
    { rank=same; h, i, j, k }
    { rank=same; l, m, n }
    { rank=same; o, p, q, r }
    { rank=same; s, t }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, you can specify in the dot language that certain nodes have the same 'rank', i.e. are located on the same layer.

How can I do this in Mathematica 11.2?

IMO this question has already been asked:

- [Graph plotting: specify layers for layered drawing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56245/graph-plotting-specify-layers-for-layered-drawing)
- [Plotting Network with LayeredGraphPlot with specific order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46018/plotting-network-with-layeredgraphplot-with-specific-order)

However, both questions are not satisfying:

1. The first one gives no example graph and hence never got answered.
2. The second has gotten an answer specific to the example (actual manual placement).

Furthermore, both questions are 4 years old, i.e. new Mathematica versions have appeared.

I have tried three approaches in Mathematica.

1. Using newer `Graph` command with `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding"}`

   ```
   Graph[{"a" <-> "b", "a" <-> "c", "a" <-> "d", "b" <-> "c", 
      "b" <-> "e", "c" <-> "e", "c" <-> "f", "d" <-> "f", "d" <-> "g", 
      "e" <-> "h", "f" <-> "h", "f" <-> "i", "f" <-> "j", "f" <-> "g", 
      "g" <-> "k", "h" <-> "o", "h" <-> "l", "i" <-> "l", "i" <-> "m", 
      "i" <-> "j", "j" <-> "m", "j" <-> "n", "j" <-> "k", "k" <-> "n", 
      "k" <-> "r", "l" <-> "o", "l" <-> "m", "m" <-> "o", "m" <-> "p", 
      "m" <-> "n", "n" <-> "q", "n" <-> "r", "o" <-> "s", "o" <-> "p", 
      "p" <-> "s", "p" <-> "t", "p" <-> "q", "q" <-> "t", "q" <-> "r", 
      "r" <-> "t", "s" <-> "z", "t" <-> "z"}, 
     GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left},
     VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", VertexSize -> {.2, .1}, 
     VertexStyle -> White, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
     EdgeStyle -> Black,
     EdgeShapeFunction -> {
       "p" <-> "q" -> {"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -0.66},
       "p" <-> "t" -> {"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -0.66},
       "m" <-> "o" -> {"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> 1}
       }]
   ```

   **UPDATED**:

   - Orientation (comment by kglr)
   - Specified edges which should be curved otherwise they are hidden (answer by kglr)

[image]

2. Using older `GraphPlot` command with promising feature `VertexCoordinateRules`:

   ```
   GraphPlot[{"a" -> "b", "a" -> "c", "a" -> "d", "b" -> "c", "b" -> "e", "c" -> "e",
     "c" -> "f", "d" -> "f", "d" -> "g", "e" -> "h", "f" -> "h", "f" -> "i", "f" -> "j",
     "f" -> "g", "g" -> "k", "h" -> "o", "h" -> "l", "i" -> "l", "i" -> "m", "i" -> "j", 
     "j" -> "m", "j" -> "n", "j" -> "k", "k" -> "n", "k" -> "r", "l" -> "o", "l" -> "m",
     "m" -> "o", "m" -> "p", "m" -> "n", "n" -> "q", "n" -> "r", "o" -> "s", "o" -> "p",
     "p" -> "s", "p" -> "t", "p" -> "q", "q" -> "t", "q" -> "r", "r" -> "t", "s" -> "z",
     "t" -> "z"},
    VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> False,
    VertexCoordinateRules -> Flatten[{
       (# -> {0, Automatic}) & /@ {"a"},
       (# -> {1, Automatic}) & /@ {"b", "c", "d"},
       (# -> {2, Automatic}) & /@ {"e", "f", "g"},
       (# -> {3, Automatic}) & /@ {"h", "i", "j", "k"},
       (# -> {4, Automatic}) & /@ {"l", "m", "n"},
       (# -> {5, Automatic}) & /@ {"o", "p", "q", "r"},
       (# -> {6, Automatic}) & /@ {"s", "t"},
       (# -> {7, Automatic}) & /@ {"z"}
       }, 1]]
   ```

[image]

3. Using older `LayeredGraphPlot` (only supports `VertexCoordinateRules` with `SpringElectricalEmbedding`)

   ```
   LayeredGraphPlot[{"a" -> "b", "a" -> "c", "a" -> "d", "b" -> "c", "b" -> "e",
     "c" -> "e", "c" -> "f", "d" -> "f", "d" -> "g", "e" -> "h", "f" -> "h", "f" -> "i",
     "f" -> "j", "f" -> "g", "g" -> "k", "h" -> "o", "h" -> "l", "i" -> "l", "i" -> "m", 
     "i" -> "j", "j" -> "m", "j" -> "n", "j" -> "k", "k" -> "n", "k" -> "r", "l" -> "o",
     "l" -> "m", "m" -> "o", "m" -> "p", "m" -> "n", "n" -> "q", "n" -> "r", "o" -> "s",
     "o" -> "p", "p" -> "s", "p" -> "t", "p" -> "q", "q" -> "t", "q" -> "r", "r" -> "t",
     "s" -> "z", "t" -> "z"},
     Left, DirectedEdges -> False, VertexLabeling -> True]
   ```

[image]

Each with limitations, but most importantly only `VertexCoordinateRules` seem to be a possibility to have something similar as in the dot language.

**Issues/Questions**

1. <s>How can I switch the orientation in my first approach?   Also a few edges are not visible, e.g. edge `p--q` (a tiny bit thicker edges `p--s` and `s--q`).</s>
2. For the most promising second approach, the edge `h--o` is almost not visible: `h--o` is bended in the graphviz version (as done in approach 3). How I can I fix this?
3. I could imagine to use the first or third approach to generate a first layout and then manually fix the x-value of the nodes. How could I do this?

Comment: Re: point 3, you can use `AbsoluteOptions[graph, VertexCoordinates]` to retrieve the actual coordinates used by a `Graph[]` object.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. for that you can use `GraphEmbedding`.

Comment: @Vitaliy, forgot about that. :) Tho, one would hope `GraphEmbedding` was in the "See Also" for `GraphLayout`...

Comment: to change  the orientation in approach use `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}`

Comment: If you can export coordinates from your DOT implementation you can use them in `Graph` via `VertexCoordinates ->`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
edges = {"a"<->"b","a"<->"c","a"<->"d","b"<->"c","b"<->"e","c"<->"e","c"<->"f",
 "d"<->"f", "d"<->"g","e"<->"h","f"<->"h","f"<->"i","f"<->"j","f"<->"g","g"<->"k",
 "h"<->"o","h"<->"l", "i"<->"l","i"<->"m","i"<->"j","j"<->"m","j"<->"n","j"<->"k",
 "k"<->"n","k"<->"r","l"<->"o", "l"<->"m","m"<->"o","m"<->"p","m"<->"n","n"<->"q",
 "n"<->"r","o"<->"s","o"<->"p","p"<->"s", "p"<->"t","p"<->"q","q"<->"t","q"<->"r",
 "r"<->"t","s"<->"z","t"<->"z"};
```

Using the sorted list of vertices as the first argument in `Graph` and using `{"LayeredigraphEmbedding", "Orientation"->Left}` as the setting for the option `GraphLayout` and using `"CurvedArc"` as `EdgeShapeFunction` solves part 1 of the question:

```
vertices = Union[Flatten[List @@@ edges]];

Graph[vertices, edges, 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", VertexSize -> .3, 
  VertexStyle -> White, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeStyle -> Black, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc", 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

A more convenient approach is to use `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` and specify the number of vertices in each layer as the value of the sub-option `"VertexPartition"`:

```
layers = {1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1};
Graph[vertices, edges, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding",  "VertexPartition" -> layers}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> White, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], EdgeStyle -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> Large ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! IMO the `MultipartiteEmbedding` with layer specs is really the way to go here. I am not sure whether sooner or later I would have realized that I should provide the list of vertices alphabetically sorted to get them in the correct layer. I am really happy that you pointed out this 'detail'. BTW I updated the first approach by applying the undocumented `CurvedArc` with a manually adjusted curvature only to the required edges. I noticed that I had overlooked several overlapping edges. Therefore I guess one should not recommend this approach.

Comment: Now I have a graph where I want to use `MultipartiteEmbedding` with layers as you have described but I want a top to bottom orientation. I tried to use `"Orientation" -> Top`. However, I get the error `Graph::moptx: Method option Orientation in MultipartiteLayout is not one of {VertexPartition}.`. This looks like Mathematica does not support this. Do you know again where I could look for a solution?

Comment: @Hotschke, you can use `SetProperty[g, 
 VertexCoordinates -> RotationTransform[-Pi/2][GraphEmbedding[g]]]` where `g = Graph[vertices, edges, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding",  "VertexPartition" -> layers}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> White, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], EdgeStyle -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> Large ]`

Comment: Thanks again! You are helping me quite a bit, not the first time. I am really glad that the stackexchange network makes this possible.